# Is it possible to have a collection of dynamic generic traits?

Tags: rust

I have a trait with generic type parameter. I want to put different objects that implements this trait in a collection. Object have different type parameters.

When I do it, compiler tells me that I need to specify generic type parameter. I actually don't need this generic type information for my case, so some kind of wildcard would work for me. Let me show the code, as it shows my intention better:

```
trait Test<T> {
    fn test(&self) -> T;
}
struct Foo;
struct Bar;
impl Test<i64> for Foo {
    fn test(&self) -> i64 {
        println!("foo");
        42
    }
}
impl Test<String> for Bar {
    fn test(&self) -> String {
        println!("bar");
        "".to_string()
    }
}

fn main() {
    // I'm not going to invoke test method which uses generic type parameter.
    // So some kind of wildcard would work for me.
    // But underscore is not wildcard and this does not compile.
    let xs: Vec<Box<dyn Test<_>>> = vec![Box::new(Foo), Box::new(Bar)];
    xs.iter().map(|x| {
        // do some stuff, but not invoke Test::test() method, so I don't need type information
        ()
    });
}
```

The error is:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Bar: Test<i64>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:24:57
   |
24 |     let xs: Vec<Box<dyn Test<_>>> = vec![Box::new(Foo), Box::new(Bar)];
   |                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Test<i64>` is not implemented for `Bar`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <Bar as Test<std::string::String>>
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn Test<i64>`
```

I understand why compiler gives me this error: I put Foo first and it has i64 as a type parameter. After that compiler expects only i64 as a type parameter. But is there a way to workaround this?

Comment: If parts of your trait are useful on their own without the `T`, then make two traits.

Comment: When `Foo` implements both `Test<i64>` and `Test<String>`, then which one should `Box<Foo> as Box<Test<_>>` use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can not make it work exactly like this.

Your options to achieve a similar result are to either have your elements implement another non generic trait that you then add to your `Vec` if you do not know ahead of time which types for `T` are ultimately possible i.e. the trait is part of your public API and other crates are expected to implement it for their own types `T`.

```
trait NonGenericTest {}
trait Test2<T> : NonGenericTest {
    fn test(&self) -> T;
}

impl NonGenericTest for Foo{}
impl NonGenericTest for Bar{}

impl Test2<i64> for Foo {
    fn test(&self) -> i64 {
        println!("foo");
        42
    }
}
impl Test2<String> for Bar {
    fn test(&self) -> String {
        println!("bar");
        "".to_string()
    }
}
fn main()  {
    let xs: Vec<Box<dyn NonGenericTest>> = vec![Box::new(Foo), Box::new(Bar)];
    xs.iter().map(|x| {
        // do some stuff, but not invoke Test::test() method, so I don't need type information
        ()
    });
}
```

Or if you know all possible types of `T` ahead of time you could change the `T` in your trait to an enum that contains all the types you want to support here:

```
enum TestResult {
  ResultI64(i64),
  ResultString(String),
}

trait Test {
    fn test(&self) -> TestResult;
}
struct Foo;
struct Bar;
impl Test for Foo {
    fn test(&self) -> TestResult {
        println!("foo");
        TestResult::ResultI64(42)
    }
}
impl Test for Bar {
    fn test(&self) -> TestResult {
        println!("bar");
        TestResult::ResultString("".to_string())
    }
}
fn main(){
    let xs: Vec<Box<dyn Test>> = vec![Box::new(Foo), Box::new(Bar)];
    xs.iter().map(|x| {
        // do some stuff, but not invoke Test::test() method, so I don't need type information
        ()
    });
}
```

Comment: There is a third option, to make a sub-trait, such as in this [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a17916484920c5044a1b7d5308d21c07). Not the prettiest code, because of that `PhantomData` all around, but it works.

Comment: That seems useful to me, but I am not sure why that `PhantomData` is needed or what it does.

Comment: The `PhantomData` is necessary to distinguish between `Foo as Test<i64>` and `Foo as Test<String>`, when `Foo` implements both.

Comment: If you try writing: `impl<T: Test<U>, U> Test2 for T` it will fail with an error saying that `U` is unconstrained.

Comment: @FlyingFoX In the first case, that we have `x` being `Box<dyn NonGenericTest>`, what can we do with it if not invoke the `test()` method?

Comment: @m0ur you should be able to call all methods that are defined in `NonGenericTest`. The example does not list any methods in that trait and you will have to add your own.